# Track down system inavailability event on MacOS El Capitan

Tags: connection, osx-el-capitan, mac-pro, hybrid-sleep

We have a Mac Pro tower with El Capitan on it. We use it as a build machine for our Apple development. Almost everyday team viewer starts to show the machine as unavailable. Build agent for our CI server also disconnects. When in the morning we check the machine, mouse clicks don't seem to "wake it up", although the box itself is running (light indication, fans, etc).

Resetting the machine starts everything up just fine.

When looking into system.log with Console, we see that entries have been written to it even when the machine was unresponsive/disconnected, but it's hard to track down actual event that causes the machine to enter such state.

Perhaps there is a software or a generic approach of investigating log that will facilitate the search of the cause of such behavior? Thanks.

Comment: System logs are often too verbose and hard to track down problems with at times.  I would start by disabling any sort of power save and 'power nap' modes (hint: pmset via terminal).  Also have you reached out to Team Viewer to see if this is a known issue?

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at power nap, etc. Since build agent which is supposed to be constantly connected to our CI server disconnects as well, I suppose apps are either suspended (all apps), or have no network connectivity.